Mouse callbacks {Click Functionality} Not Working in Qtile Shutdown Widget (archCraft linux)
I'm trying to create a minimalistic GUI in Qtile for shutdown, restart, and logout options using a simple widget, but I'm having trouble with the click functionality
I use archcraft linux...
while I know how to do it with the terminal I am trying to bring my qtile WM to as close as to a
Desktop Environment and mostly because I am a linux newbie
I’ve added the following snippet to my config.py:
#these lines at beginning 
# Define colors
power_bar_bg = "#2E3440"
button_bg = "#3B4252"
button_fg = "#D8DEE9"

# Define functions for power actions
def shutdown(qtile):
    os.system("poweroff")

def restart(qtile):
    os.system("reboot")

def logout(qtile):
    qtile.cmd_shutdown()


#this is snippet that's near the end of the config file
screens = [
    Screen(
        right=bar.Gap(var_gap_right),
        left=bar.Gap(var_gap_left),
        top=bar.Gap(var_gap_top),
        bottom=bar.Bar(
            [
                widget.TextBox(
                    text="⏻",
                    foreground=button_fg,
                    background=button_bg,
                    fontsize=20,
                    padding=10,
                    mouse_callbacks={'Button1': shutdown}
                ),
                widget.TextBox(
                    text="↺",
                    foreground=button_fg,
                    background=button_bg,
                    fontsize=20,
                    padding=10,
                    mouse_callbacks={'Button1': restart}
                ),
                widget.TextBox(
                    text="➡️",
                    foreground=button_fg,
                    background=button_bg,
                    fontsize=20,
                    padding=10,
                    mouse_callbacks={'Button1': logout}
                ),
            ],
            30,  # height of the bar
            background=power_bar_bg,
        ),
    )
]

the resultant desktop had this at the bottom
while this is pretty much what I expected yet the problem being I am not able to click on the buttons
and the mouse callbacks are not working as intended ..they are not working at all
